# Save current user_id as default post owner field automatically in laravel eloquent models

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Suppose I have a Post model by this Attributes :

```
post_id
title
description
owner       //=> type same as user_id of User Model
created_at
updated_at
```

And now I want to fill out `owner` field with current (Authenticated) user ID on `store` action of `PostConroller` when using `Create` Model. (`owner` value not included in `$dataArray` and should automatically get `user_id`):

```
Post::create($dataArray)
```

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what do you mean by automatically, but you can add `user_id` to an array:

```
$dataArray['owner'] = $user_id;
Post::create($dataArray);
```

But usually you're using collections when creating new model, so:

```
$dataCollection->put('owner', $user_id);
Post::create($dataCollection);
```

will add `user_id` to collection.

Also, do not forget to add `owner` to [`$fillable`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#mass-assignment) array.

Comment: In fact I do not want to get `Auth::user()->user_id` and hold in `$dataArray`. I want it automatically set as default value of `owner` field by  current authenticated user_id

Comment: Can you describe what exactly you mean by automatically please?

Comment: when user send a form contains values of Post Model, the `owner` field fill out with `user_id` of that user.

Comment: Ok. If you have a lot of `create()` clauses in your app, you could use Eloquent Event, which will add `owner` field automatically when you're using `create()` on `Post` model: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#events

Comment: I wouldn't recommend setting owner to $fillable array because it's bad security. Anyone can set anyone as owner then.

Answer (score 3):

In your model class, add save function override:

```
public function save(array $options = array())
{
    $this->owner = auth()->id();
    parent::save($options);
}
```

That's automatic. Just be carefull if you tend to use save in any other scenario so you don't overwrite owner.

Comment: I think this answer is the best assumption for what "automatic" means here -- Also this negates the need to set owner in $fillable which is bad practice as it removes the guard Laravel provides; the ownership field is NOT something that should be mass assignable!

Answer (score 1):

I@m stuck on this too.
Automatic means that you can provide ALL other data, but when a create is called, the model just knows to add user  to equal Auth:id()

like this? (but this isn't working for me

```
protected static function booting(): void
{
    static::creating(function ($product) {
        $product->user_id = Auth::id();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public function save(array $options = []) {
    if (!isset($this->user_id) || !(intval($this->user_id)>0)  ) {
        $this->user_id = auth()->id();
    }

    return parent::save($options);
}
```

- If your user->id's are number
- Remember the return, else save is always false